# Using bootstrap modal to load different contents with jquery validations

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap model to edit table values. It works perfectly. But when I'm using BootstrapValidator plugin to validate that modal there's a problem. Problem is when I click edit first time and load model it works normally. Then if I click edit again in the same page, validation errors belongs to previous one still shows. Screen shot displays here,

[image]

Modal Call

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dealModal" onclick="ajax_get_edit_data('.$id.');"></a>
```

Validations

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {     
    $('#dealForm')
        .bootstrapValidator({
            message: 'This value is not valid',
            fields: {
                deal_description: {
                    message: 'The deal discription is not valid',
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The deal discription is required and can\'t be empty'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        .on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
            // Prevent form submission
            e.preventDefault();

            // Get the form instance
            var $form = $(e.target);

            // Get the BootstrapValidator instance
            var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');

            // Use Ajax to submit form data
            //$.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(result) {
            //  console.log(result);
            //}, 'json');
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After form is submitted, call [resetForm](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/api/#reset-form) method:

```
...
var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');
...
// After successful post
bv.resetForm();
```